# Ingesting stream counters from Cloud Pubsub to Bigtable using Google Cloud Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I want to consume data from PubSub and maintain the counter of some data fields and maintain the real-time counters for the same, how can I do the same in Google Cloud DataFlow. I can Sink the data into Bigtable, but how do I update the data?

I am able to update the bigtable, but not counters, it gets replaced with the new values

```
pubsub_data = (
               p 
               | 'Read from pub sub' >> beam.io.ReadFromPubSub(subscription=input_subscription)
               | 'De-Serialize' >> ParDo(PreProcess())
               | 'Count' >> ParDo(Countit())
               | 'Conversion string to row object' >> beam.ParDo(CreateRowFn()) 
               | "Write Data" >> WriteToBigTable( project_id=PROJECT, instance_id=INSTANCE, table_id=TABLE)
              )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do this with [state and timers](https://beam.apache.org/blog/timely-processing/), outputting running totals and such from your `Countit` DoFn.

Comment: I was not aware of these, ended up writing a similar logic using Spark Structured Streaming, using the "update" mode, and it was faster as well.